# XSRF-TOKEN not generating in laravel api with next.js app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-api

XSRF-TOKEN not generating in laravel API with next.js app in live server. but everything is working fine on localhost. I am using Laravel as the backend and next.js as the frontend.

**Localhost Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to generate APP_KEY on your production environment, check .env file and in case APP_KEY is empty try to call `php artisan key:generate` command.

Comment: run this command, still not generating...

Comment: maybe a cache issue, try running php artisan optimize:clear or php artisan cache:clear, without more debugging information it's difficult to find out what is going on, I can only suggest you comparing your server and localhost laravel configs